# How do I merge two dataframes on multiple columns when one of the columns is an index in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

When merging on multiple columns, this would work:

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'left', left_on = ['col1','col2','col3'], right_on = ['colA', 'colB','colC'])
```

what do I do if I have to use the index on one of the dataframes to join since that would require me to use `left_index = True` in order to preserve the left df index while building newdf?

Comment: do you mean that one of the columns from ```['col1','col2','col3']``` is the ```index``` in one of the dataframes?

Comment: @sophocles Yes. My current workaround is to duplicate the index as a temporary column and use that to merge on, but I would like to know if it's possible to include the index as a column to merge on while merging the two dataframes

Comment: if you reset the index within the merge step, it won't change the original df1 or df2 frames, so just something like `pd.merge(df1.rest_index(), df2.reset_index(), how = 'left', left_on = ['col1','col2','col3'], right_on = ['colA', 'colB','colC'])` should be fine.

Comment: Just wanted to put this here that 

newdf = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'left', left_on = [df1.index,'col2','col3'], right_on = [df2.index, 'colB','colC']) 

also works

Answer (score 0):

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'left', left_on = [df1.index,'col2','col3'], right_on = [df2.index, 'colB','colC'])
```

also works in addition to @StevenS solution.